# POSIX semaphore with related processes running threads

Tags: linux, pthreads, posix, mutex, semaphore

I have an assignment to implement Producer consumer problem in a convoluted way(may be to test my understanding). The parent process should set up a shared memory. The unnamed semaphores(for empty count and filled count) should be initialized and a mutex should be initialized. Then two child processes are created, a producer child and a consumer child. Each child process should create a new thread which should do the job.

PS: I have read that the semaphore's should be kept in a shared memory as they would be shared by different processes.

Please provide some hints, or suggest changes.

So far, I have done this:

```
struct shmarea 
{
unsigned short int read;
unsigned short int max_size;
char scratch[3][50];
unsigned short int write;
sem_t sem1;// Empty slot semaphore
sem_t sem2;// Filled slot Semaphore
}; 

void *thread_read(void* args);
void *thread_write(void *args);

pthread_mutex_t work_mutex;

struct shmarea *shma;

int main()
{
int fork_value,i=0,shmid;
printf("Parent process id is %d\n\n",getpid());
int res1,res2;
key_t key;
char *path = "/tmp";
int id = 'S';

key = ftok(path, id);
shmid =  shmget(key,getpagesize(),IPC_CREAT|0666);

printf("Parent:Shared Memory id = %d\n",id);
shma = shmat(shmid,0,0);    

shma->read = 0;
shma->max_size = 3;
shma->write = 0; 

pthread_t a_thread;
pthread_t b_thread;

void *thread_result1,*thread_result2;

res1 = sem_init(&(shma->sem1),1,3);//Initializing empty slot sempahore
res2 = sem_init(&(shma->sem2),1,0);//Initializing filled slot sempahore

res1 = pthread_mutex_init(&work_mutex,NULL);

while(i<2)
{
    fork_value = fork();
    if(fork_value > 0)
    {
        i++;
    }
    if(fork_value == 0)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {           
            printf("***0***\n");
            //sem_t sem1temp = shma->sem1;
            char ch;int res;
            res= pthread_create(&a_thread,NULL,thread_write,NULL);
        }
        if(i==1)
        {
            printf("***1***\n");        
            //sem_t sem2temp = shma->sem2;      
            int res;
            char ch;
            res= pthread_create(&b_thread,NULL,thread_read,NULL);
        }
    }
}
int wait_V,status;
res1 = pthread_join(a_thread,&thread_result1);
res2 = pthread_join(b_thread,&thread_result2);
}

void *thread_read(void *args)
{   
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&(shma->sem2));
        pthread_mutex_lock(&work_mutex);
        printf("The buf read from consumer:%s\n",shma->scratch[shma->read]);
        shma->read = (shma->read+1)%shma->max_size;             
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&work_mutex);
        sem_post(&(shma->sem1));
    }
} 

void *thread_write(void *args)
{
    char buf[50];
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&(shma->sem1));    
        pthread_mutex_lock(&work_mutex);
        read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,sizeof(buf)); 
        strcpy(shma->scratch[shma->write],buf);
        shma->write = (shma->write+1)%shma->max_size;               
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&work_mutex);
        sem_post(&(shma->sem2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Your biggest problem by far is that you have managed to write a fork bomb.  Because you don't exit either child in the fork loop each child is going to fall through and loop around and create their own children until you crash or bring the system down.  You want something more like this:

```
while(i < 2)
{
    fork_value = fork();

    if(fork_value > 0)
        i++;

    if(fork_value == 0)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            printf("0 child is pid %d\n", getpid());

            int res;
            res = pthread_create(&a_thread,NULL,thread_write,NULL);
            res = pthread_join(a_thread,&thread_result1);
            exit(0);
        }

        if(i==1)
        {
            printf("1 child is pid %d\n", getpid());

            int res;
            res = pthread_create(&b_thread,NULL,thread_read,NULL);
            res = pthread_join(b_thread,&thread_result2);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    wait(NULL);
```

Notice the `wait` on the children which you neglected.

(2) Always check your return codes.  They are like safety belts, a bit of a drag but so helpful when you crash. (Yes, I didn't take my advice here but you should.)

(3) These names are awful.

```
unsigned short int read;
unsigned short int write;
```

Stay away from naming variables after system calls.  It's confusing and just asking for trouble.

(4) Terminology wise, processes with a common ancestor, like these, are related.  The parent can open shared memory and other resources and pass it on to the children.  Unrelated processes would, for example, multiple instances of program launched from different terminals.  They can share resources but not in the "inherited" way forked processes do.

It's late and didn't get around to looking at what you are doing with the threads and such but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the helping comments. While posting the question I had omitted the clean up code. The fork bomb was indeed the root cause of failure. I put those lines and My program works :) So I have few doubts 1.Why do we have to put the semaphores in shared memory even though they are related processes as per the terminology you have said in point 4. since they are related shouldn't the global variables, semaphores be automatically map to the child processes and there threads. If i don't keep semaphores in shm mem, and keep them as global variables will there be issues?

Comment: There is a wrinkle here that may be confusing you.  First let's establish that a child inherits a bunch of things file descriptors, share memory segments, etc., from the parent.  But it only gets a *copy* of the program memory e.g. stack, code, heap, etc.  So any changes the child or parent make to that memory after the fork do not effect each other.  Now POSIX has 2 families of semaphores, sysV and the new "posix" semaphores (although *both* are part of POSIX).  The kernel manages SysV semaphore's data itself; posix semaphores keep information in user space.  So if were using sysV sems you

Comment: would not need shared memory.  You would have a copy of semid, already established permissions with the kernel, etc., in the parent.  A *copy* in this instance would work ok because it is (conceptually) like a pointer to something in the kernel.  Posix sems, OTOH, keep the sem_t data in user space.  This data gets changed with each semaphore related system call.  If it were kept in normal (not shared) process memory then parent & child would be operating on separate copies - with predictably bad results.  You are using Posix semaphore so you have to use shared memory.

Comment: Their is, btw, nothing wrong with using sysV shared memory (as you are doing) with posix semaphores.  It's just useful to know that both families of IPC behave a little differently.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Duck for the detailed explanation. I you don't mind, will tag you for some doubts in future on SO.